# Group theory and conjugacy class

Tags: group-theory

My teacher wrote the following two statements without proving them

1) If $G$ has two conjugacy class then $|G|=2$

2) If $a\in G$ and the conjugacy class to $a$ contains two elements only then $G$ has a non-trivial proper subgroup.

Does anyone know how to prove these?

Thank you.

Comment: For 1), have you learned that the size of a conjugacy class divides the size of the group?

Comment: @pjs36, yes, but Why does $|G|=2$ and not 4 or 6 .....

Comment: 1) The identity is always in its own conjugacy class, hence...
Also, I am a bit confused by 2). Cauchy's theorem tells you that any group of composite order has a non-trivial subgroup.

Comment: @MrDi If $G$ has two conjugacy classes then one of them has size $1$ and the other has size, say, $n$, and $|G| = 1 + n$ .What happens if you take this modulo $n$?

Comment: For 2), consider the set $\{x\in G:xax^{-1}=a\}$.

Comment: If $\;G\;$ doesn't have to be *finite*, it is false that if it has two conjugacy classes then $\;|G|=2\;$ . There are infinite groups in which any two elements different from the unity are conjugated.

Answer (score 0):

$1)$ 
Note that $$o(G)=\sum c_a$$ where $c_a$ denotes the elements of the conjugate class of $a$. This equation works because in $G$ we have defined an equivalence relation. $a\sim b$ iff exist an $c$ such that $a=c^{-1}bc$.

$2)$

For a finite group G and an element $x$  we know that the number of conjugates of $x$ in $G$ is equal to the number of cosets of $CG(x)$( normalizer of $x$ in $G$). Since we have only two conjugates $CG(x) $has index $2$ in $G$. But any subgroup of index $2$ in $G$ is normal  Hence $CG(x)$ is normal in G. Since $$|G : CG(x)| = 2$$ we have $G\neq CG(x)$. On the other hand $CG(x)\neq {e}$ as $x\neq e$ (otherwise $CG(x) = G$) and $x$ is an element of $CG(x)$.